# add croped image into original image

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, php-gd

i will crop a part of image and blur the original image 
problem is : i want replace cropped image into original blur image,
how to can do it?
i do crop image with [jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html) from JQUERY framework 
and this code is for crop

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
    $jpeg_quality = 90;
    $src = $row['address'];
    $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );   imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);
```

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to achieve, but could you post a quick mockup of what you're trying to do? Also do you want a purely GD solution or with the use of imagemagick?

Comment: really better for me GD solution.

Comment: Still unsure about this: Do you just want to cut a part of the image and have it blurred? Or do you want to blur an image, then overlay an unblurred part of it (like some do to fill 16:9 video with 4:3 footage)?

Comment: is true :  do you want to blur an image, then overlay an unblurred part of it , really i want crop part of an image and I have the original photo blur then replace croped image on blured image

Comment: after crop and blur main image, parts will be in orginal place into main image.